# Unity | How to Copy the Values of a GameObject instead of it's address?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

For example:
List = {a,b}

```
private List<GameObject> FunctionName(List<GameObject> List)
{
    List<GameObject> ListClone = List;
    ListClone.RemoveAt(1);
    
    return List;
}
```

output: a

Another example:

```
GameObject a = GameObject b;
Destroy(b);
return a;
```

output: null

How can i copy the Value not the Address, so that the old Objects doesn't get changed with it?

This is the reason while nothing works like it should and i need a work-around for everything and it takes 10x the amount of time to do anything, so please enlighten me.

Comment: You should research the difference between reference types and value types. Here's a start: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: it's not linking anything ... you assign the reference of `b` and store it in a variable called `a` ... => They both now point to the same object ... Se for your list example ... Sounds like you should go through some very basic c# and in general Object Oriented Programming tutorials ;)

Comment: @RetiredNinja i did, but how can i only assign the values instead of it direction to the same point now?

Comment: You want to clone the object: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/09/09/cloning-objects-in-c-and-net-core/

Answer (score -2):

If you want to copy the memory-address:

```
List<GameObject> A = B;
```

If you want to copy the value of the memory-address:

```
List<GameObject> A = new List<GameObject>(B);
```